# Ordering by number of hasMany records - COUNT(RelatedModel.field)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model, containable

I have a model, Track, that hasMany Vote.  the Vote model has a field called "value".  What I wish to do is to sort Track records by the sum of the values of their votes (which means unfortunately I can't use counterCache).

Of course, trying to put something like `'order'=>'SUM(Vote.value)'` fails with an "unknown column..." error.

I would just get everything in a find('all') and then sort it out afterwards, but I need pagination too.

The best idea I've come up with is to add a field to the Track model that keeps track of the total value of all votes - something like what counterCache does but reflecting the different value of various votes.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up adding a column ("vote_score") to the Track model and updating it when a vote is added/deleted.  Here's the code, in case anyone is interested.  It appears to work, haven't tested it extensively though.  In the Vote model:

```
public function afterSave(){
    $this->Track->id = $this->data['Vote']['track_id'];
    $this->Track->saveField('vote_score','vote_score' + $this->data['Vote']['value']);
}

public function beforeDelete(){
    $vote = $this->Vote->read();
    $this->Track->id = $vote['Vote']['track_id'];
    $this->Track->saveField('vote_score','vote_score' - $vote['Vote']['value']);
    return true;
}
```